# How to use Mysql database data in javascript widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, json, widget

I'm creating a widget for users to place on their blogs to direct traffic to my coupon code site. I want the widget to access the database and output the 5 top coupons of the day. Here is what I will them place on their site:

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="example-widget-container"></div>
```

Now the script.js file looks like:

```
(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
    script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // Same thing but for IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
            scriptLoadHandler();
        }
    };
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        /******* Load CSS *******/
        var css_link = $("<link>", { 
            rel: "stylesheet", 
            type: "text/css", 
            href: "style.css" 
        });
        css_link.appendTo('head');          

        /******* Load HTML *******/
        var jsonp_url = "http://www.mydomain.com/widget_data.php";
        $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
          $('#example-widget-container').html("This data comes from another server: " + data.html);
        });
    });
}

})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

The problem I'm having is how do I return a json array to the js file, and how do I loop through it to output a unordered list with each coupon being its own list item?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax,

send a HttpRequest from the widget to the web server, 
send back from the server a json response, for example in PHP would be something like this

```
...
//access the database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM coupons LIMIT 5";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {      
  $coupons[] = $row;
}

//return json object
echo json_encode($coupons);
...
```

Once the js widget has received the json string, you can convert it to a js object to do what you need to

```
JSON.parse(strJSON)
```

jQuery ajax request example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show me how to make the ajax request? I was initially using jQuery and the .getJSON function, but I really don't like it. Thanks!

Comment: added a jQuery example from jQuery documentation